What could cause ART (Android Runtime) to deadlock while unloading a native library?
I have been trying to debug a non user perceivable crash in my app (I think it happens in the background) that originated from the Android Runtime due to possibly a deadlock/thread contention.
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000004f560  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+32)
  #01  pc 0x000000000030d9a8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Mutex::ExclusiveLock(art::Thread*)+280)
  #02  pc 0x00000000005fe8b4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Libraries::UnloadNativeLibraries()+96)
  #03  pc 0x00000000003ba968  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::CollectGarbageInternal(art::gc::collector::GcType, art::gc::GcCause, bool, unsigned int)+876)
  #04  pc 0x00000000003ba50c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGC(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, bool, unsigned int)+164)

Caused DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 failure : SuspendThreadByPeer timed out: 14060 (HeapTaskDaemon), state&flags: 0x9, priority: 5, barriers: 0x<sanitized>, ours: 0x<sanitized>, barrier value: 1, nsusps: 0, ncheckpts: 0, thread_info: Target states: [14060 (HeapTaskDaemon) S 1097 1097 0 0 -1 1077936192 231570 372 345 3 170 481 0 1 24 4 74, 14060 (HeapTaskDaemon) S 1097 1097 0 0 -1 1077936192 390055 372 345 3 219 832 0 1 24 4 74]1@517142581380 Final wait time: 4.010s

I have looked into source code of UnloadNativeLibraries here and it looks like this jni_libraries_lock_ is acquired when loading a native shared library.
However I just couldn't wrap my head around how this could happen. In my app I do a native library of my own that I load at the runtime. I don't know if it is this native library that is doing something wrong.
What are some things that a native library could be doing so that ART couldn't manage to acquire the lock? Is there anything else that I can do in order to debug this issue?

It isn't necessarily due to your own native lib. See if you can identify what lib is being loaded at that point -- through either the logs if you have access to those or the thread dump if the trace on the thread that's holding that lock gives any indication.
A lib could take long to load/unload if it's large or doing too much in JNI_OnLoad/JNI_OnUnload. See the tip here about using RegisterNatives for better performance.
Btw, looks like this deadlock will be fixed in a future ART release.
